# Configuring ACL on CentOS

Tags: centos, mount, access-control-list

I'm attempting to configure the following things via an ACL on CentOS 6:

1. Allow UserX to mount any directory without sudo
2. Allow UserX ability to edit /etc/fstab without sudo

Having never configured an ACL before, I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Delegating `mount` in this way is best handled through `sudo`, as ACLs are inappropriate (read: I cannot for the life of me think of a way to do it via ACLs).

If the only file they need to edit is fstab, you'd probably be better off changing the group ownership to a custom group, and giving UserX secondary group membership of that group.

Upshot: IMHO, nothing that can be done without ACLs should be done with them; they complicate life.  In this case, both tasks are better done without them.

**Edit**: try passwordless `sudo` for the user who needs to mount/unmount.  A `sudoers` entry like

```
userx    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
```

may well do what you need it to, though you'd better hope that userx doesn't feel like experimenting or messing around!

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to Linux systems administration (I usually just develop on it!). Changing the permissions of the file is a perfect solution for the fstab issue. However doing a sudo requires a user to input the password and this isn't suitable. I need to be able to mount/unmount a share at the command line without a sudo.